# how to make a unique batch number per day?

Tags: php, mysql

how to make a batch number per day,
for example, TODAY I manufacture products with no batch:

1. produk A With batch number =>  29092016-1
2. produk B With batch number =>  29092016-2
3. produk C With batch number =>  29092016-3

TOMORROW no batch should be:

1. produk A With batch number =>  30092016-1
2. produk B With batch number =>  30092016-2
3. produk C With batch number =>  30092016-3

DAY AFTER TOMORROW no batch should be:

1. produk A With batch number =>  01102016-1
2. produk B With batch number =>  01102016-2
3. produk C With batch number =>  01102016-3

How do I have to write a code in PHP ??

i have code but no working :

```
$data_oto     = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select max(id_batch2) as maksi from batch2"));

function buatkode($nomor_terakhir, $kunci, $jumlah_karakter = 0){
$nomor_baru = intval(substr($nomor_terakhir, strlen($kunci))) + 1;
$nomor_baru_plus_nol = str_pad($nomor_baru, $jumlah_karakter, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$kode = $kunci . $nomor_baru_plus_nol;
return $kode;}
$date_now=date('dmY');
$batch=buatkode($data_oto['maksi'],$date_now, 1);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO batch2(id_batch2,id_item) VALUES('$batch','$_POST[item]')");
```

Comment: You mean, you want to know the code to create ddmmyy-1 daily?

Comment: yes i  want to know the code

Comment: go to the php manual and look up `date`

Comment: why you say it is not working? you have only one batch number, so why the loop is needed?

Comment: Hey folks, be aware @SigitDwiPrasetyo is actually looking for a cron/task job, as indicated by his comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761098/how-to-make-a-unique-batch-number-per-day/39761225#comment66818717_39761225

Comment: You don't necessarily need to 'create' a batch number. If you have a date and an autoincrementing PRIMARY KEY then the batch number can be calculated 'on-the-fly' -assuming deletions are not allowed

Comment: @SigitDwiPrasetyo every day product 1 should have a substring 1.Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating a batch code it is a better way to including date on it. But for identifying the product and and its batch it should be better to include some standard format on the entire code

First 6 letters  => date

Next three letters => Identify Product using any product identification code with preceding zeros or any symbols For Example "P1"

Next three letters => identifying batch code with preceding zeros or any symbols For Example "B1"

You can generate this by following method:

```
$date = date("dmY");
$product_identification = "P1";//this can be replaced by your own variable
$product_code = str_pad($product_identification, 3, "-", STR_PAD_LEFT); //Here "-" symbol used for preceding letters we can replace with 0 if required
$batch_identification = "B1"; //this can be replaced by your own variable
$batch_code = str_pad($batch_identification, 3, "-", STR_PAD_LEFT); //Here "-" symbol used for preceding letters we can replace with 0 if required

$code = $date.$product_code.$batch_code;

print $code; //will output 29092016-P1-B1
```

Based on this way you can generate such codes by your own

Comment: wow, way to complicate the hell out of this question/answer :-D  btw, love it!! lol

Comment: how generating code  the "B1" can change when add data ?

Comment: "B1" is any string that you can use your own batch code or identification number of your batch

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("dmY");
for ($i = 1; $i <= n; $i++) { //n = number of products
    $batchNumber = "$date-$i";
    echo $batchNumber;
}
```

Comment: i try this but not working when add data, data showing always 29092016-1, no additional.

Comment: you say the "-1" part does not change?

Comment: i see you replaced n by 1, it will excecute one time

Answer (score 1):

So you want to make a dmY-x ?

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 3):
    echo date('dmY') . '-' . $i.'<br>';
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: yes i wanna "-x" change when i add data, and when day is change "-x" back to number 1

Comment: Are you wanting these to run a single time, or on a daily occurrence at a given time?

Comment: i wan to run  a daily occurrence at a given time

Comment: Well that is something you should have **clearly** indicated in your original post. You have all of us giving you code for doing a one-time generation. What you need to be asking for us cronjob _(*nix*)_ or tasks _(windows)_ so might I suggest you update your original question to clearly identify that you are want this.